# Which version of php, apache, IIS will be compatible with windows 8 64 bit

Tags: php, apache, iis

I want to install php on Windows 8 but I am not able to get the right version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused with the title, you will only need to use either Apache or IIS, not both at the same time. However, you could use Apache on Windows see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi), the latest version of Apache is 2.4.10. As for PHP see [here](http://windows.php.net/download), the latest version of PHP is 5.6.1. You can manually install it, or if you're less familiar you can scroll down the page for an executable version.

If you do want to use IIS instead of Apache, then be sure to enable it in the Control Panel. Another great thing to check out (if you're using IIS) is the Web Platform installer, see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).

Comment: ok thanks :)

As I am beginner to it so facing problems.

Comment: @NeerajYadav no problem :). I'd suggest going with IIS then, since you may be used to it on your Windows system. And Web Platform Installer will help you install PHP and others extremely easily.

Comment: ok :)
I download php version 5.6.1 and its debug pack 5.6.1 not thread safe version.

Comment: @NeerajYadav Download one of the Zip versions. Example [link](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.6.1-Win32-VC11-x86.zip) here.

Comment: ok downloaded :) @user4136119